# Objects in array javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I am implementing the leaflet heatmap on my website and have problems visualising my data in the graph.

The example works by the following test data:

```
var data = [{
    lat: 24.6408,
    lng: 46.7728,
    count: 3
}, {
    lat: 50.75,
    lng: -1.55,
    count: 1
}, {
    lat: 52.6333,
    lng: 1.75,
    count: 1
}, {
    lat: 48.15,
    lng: 9.4667,
    count: 1
}, {
    lat: 52.35,
    lng: 4.9167,
    count: 2
}, {
    lat: 35.5498,
    lng: -118.917,
    count: 1
}, {
    lat: 34.1568,
    lng: -118.523,
    count: 1
}, {
    lat: 27.2498,
    lng: -80.3797,
    count: 1
}, {
    lat: 41.4789,
    lng: -81.6473,
    count: 1
}, {
    lat: 41.813,
    lng: -87.7134,
    count: 1
}, {
    lat: 41.8917,
    lng: -87.9359,
    count: 1
}, {
    lat: 35.0911,
    lng: -89.651,
    count: 1
}, {
    lat: 32.6102,
    lng: -117.03,
    count: 1
}, {
    lat: 41.758,
    lng: -72.7444,
    count: 1
}, {
    lat: 37.5741,
    lng: -122.321,
    count: 1
}, {
    lat: 42.2843,
    lng: -85.2293,
    count: 1
}, {
    lat: 34.6574,
    lng: -92.5295,
    count: 1
}, {
    lat: 41.4881,
    lng: -87.4424,
    count: 1
}, {
    lat: 25.72,
    lng: -80.2707,
    count: 1
}, {
    lat: 34.5873,
    lng: -118.245,
    count: 1
}, {
    lat: 35.8278,
    lng: -78.6421,
    count: 1
}];
```

I am trying to get my data via AJAX as follows:

```
var locationData = [];
$.ajax(heatmapLocationExtraction).done(function(data) {
    $.each(data.result, function(key, value) {
        locationData.push({
            lat: parseFloat(value.address_lat),
            lng: parseFloat(value.address_lng),
            count: parseInt(value.hitrate)
        });
    });
});
```

The data, as I create it, does not get accepted. 
When I am doing a console.log on both values, it is represented differents. How do I create the same array of objects as my test data via code?
[image]

Please note that I DON'T have a problem with the AJAX call. I have a problem with returning the data in the correct format. The thread suggested as duplicate is not related to the issue I am having.

My console.log statements are placed here:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var testData = {
             max: 8,
             data: retrieveHeatmapLocationSearchData()
    };

    console.log(testData.data);
}
```

Comment: @baao how and why is this a duplicate?!

Comment: Take a look where `var locationData = [];` is defined. Then you got your answer. @eisbehr

Comment: Yes, and? That only the definition of a variable, where he pushes the data to. Whats the problem?`@baao

Comment: That it is an empty array when he passes it to the heatmap. Just like explained in the duplicate. Or do you see the creation of the heatmap anywhere in `done` @eisbehr

Comment: @baao in the screenshot below if i click it open, i can see the data inside it, it is not empty

Comment: Where do you have console.log() @Dennis ?

Comment: Try to put the logic that creates the map inside of `done` then report back please. Post a picture of the map you're getting for example

Comment: Updated the question!